# How to search for all nodes in a sap.m.Tree?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm currently working at a MasterDetail application for my company, which provides expandable categorys represented as nodes.

[image]

The binding of the nodes and it's child nodes with a navigation property isn't a problem. However, if I want to search for a certain group node in the search field above, it only filters between the four highest nodes. It can search for the nodes on the first level, but it isn't able to find nodes if they're below the first level.

**Binding of the tree:**

```
<Tree
    selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
    id="list"
    noDataText="{masterView>/noDataText}"
    busyIndicatorDelay="{masterView>/delay}"
    items="{path: '/GroupNodes',
                parameters : {
                expand: 'ChildGroupNodes',
                navigation: {
                    'GroupNodes': 'ChildGroupNodes'
                    }
            }
    }">
    <StandardTreeItem 
        title="{Stext}"
        type="Navigation"
        press="onSelectionChange"/>
</Tree>
```

**onSearch:**

```
    onSearch: function(oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getParameters().refreshButtonPressed) {
            this.onRefresh();
            return;
        }

        var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
        if (sQuery) {
            this._oListFilterState.aSearch = [new Filter("Stext", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)];
        } else {
            this._oListFilterState.aSearch = [];
        }
        this._applyFilterSearch();
    },
```

**_applyFilterSearch:**

```
    _applyFilterSearch: function() {
        var aFilters = this._oListFilterState.aSearch.concat(this._oListFilterState.aFilter),
            oViewModel = this.getModel();

        this._oList.getBinding("items").filter(aFilters, "Application");
        
        if (aFilters.length !== 0) {
            oViewModel.setProperty("/noDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataWithFilterOrSearchText"));
        } else if (this._oListFilterState.aSearch.length > 0) {
            oViewModel.setProperty("/noDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataText"));
        }
    },
```

**Filterstate in the onInit() function:**

```
this._oListFilterState = {
    aFilter: [],
    aSearch: []
};
```

**Metadata:**

```
<EntityType Name="GroupNode" sap:content-version="1">
      <Key>
         <PropertyRef Name="Grpid"/>
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Grpid" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="8" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Id Trainingsgruppe" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <Property Name="Short" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="12" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Kürzel Trainingsgruppe" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <Property Name="Stext" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Bezeichnung Trainingsgruppe" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <Property Name="Begda" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="0" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Beginndatum" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <Property Name="Endda" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="0" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Endedatum" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <Property Name="Level" Type="Edm.Int32" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="Level" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <Property Name="Parentid" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="8" sap:unicode="false" sap:label="ParentId" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
      <NavigationProperty Name="ChildGroupNodes" Relationship="Z_HR_LSO_WORKCENTER_SRV.GroupNodeToParent" FromRole="FromRole_GroupNodeToParent" ToRole="ToRole_GroupNodeToParent"/>
      <NavigationProperty Name="GroupToTrainingType" Relationship="Z_HR_LSO_WORKCENTER_SRV.GroupToTrainingType" FromRole="FromRole_GroupToTrainingType" ToRole="ToRole_GroupToTrainingType"/>
</EntityType>
```

We're working with OData V2, so there's no possibility to implement an FilterContains.All filter.

Is it even possible to filter through the child nodes of a sap.m.Tree in the front-end?

Comment: According to the [API Reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataTreeBinding/), ODataTreeBinding via "navigation" property is deprecated. Nevertheless, filtering should be supported [as of 1.30+](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/010780932ae413405246552e67382bc54bfe2844). What's the `defaultOperationMode` of your ODataModel?

Comment: @boghyon The operationMode is set to Application. I'm aware that control filters aren't supported for operationMode.Server.

Comment: Did you mean `Client` (instead of Application)?

Comment: Ah, I meant the parameter for the filter function. I haven't set an operationMode, neither for the model nor during the binding and since the default operationMode is server, my defaultOperationMode is server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, building the tree hierarchy via [`navigation` is deprecated](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/07376f76c0bdae2785e08a9924a17301b6a2f4f0/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel.js#L2089-L2096) since 1.44. Instead, SAP recommends to leverage [metadata annotations](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EmTech/SAP+Annotations+for+OData+Version+2.0#SAPAnnotationsforODataVersion2.0-Elementedm:Property):

> The use of navigation properties to build up the hierarchy structure is deprecated and it is recommended to **use the hierarchy annotations** [...].

Once the migration to the annotation approach is done, filter either client-side or server-side.

### Client-side

- The `operationMode` of the [ODataTreeBinding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel#methods/bindTree) (or the `defaultOperationMode` of the v2.ODataModel) needs to be `"Client"`.
- When calling [`.filter`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataTreeBinding#methods/filter), the [FilterType](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.FilterType) as the 2nd argument needs to be `"Control"`.
- Here is a working **example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/moTGOT](https://embed.plnkr.co/moTGOT/?show=view%2FMaster.view.xml,preview:?sap-ui-xx-componentPreload=off)**

  [image: UI5 client side tree filtering with OData V2]

### Server-side

- For ***server-side*** filtering, only the FilterType `"Application"` and the `operationMode: "Server"` are supported. In that case, the server needs to respond to the `$filter` request with a ready-made tree structure. The same applies to paging requests for sibling and child nodes.

### Limitations

- `suspended: true` in the binding info is not yet supported [(Issue #3161)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3161).
- The above content applies to **OData V2 only**.
  V4 ODataModel doesn't support tree binding at all yet [(Issue #2728)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2728).

Comment: I am just experiencing the exact same issue. Changing the operation mode of the ODataModel from "server" to "client" solves the issue partially. The filtering works fine, but only for the items that are initially loaded into your local model. Have you found a solution to filter over the whole backend correctly?

Comment: @jor With a server side operation mode, the backend is responsible for responding filter request with tree structure, but I'm afraid there is no standardized solution how the response body should look like exactly since OData doesn't specify it. However, there is a topic that might help you further: https://ui5.sap.com/1.52.4/#/topic/a05fe0659b9c49729168a48697ce0000

Comment: Thank you very much for the provided link! As I understood all my problems should be solved when adding the "hierarchy-node-descendant-count-for" annotation.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann have you tried searching parent node, by default searching parent node only shows parent node, it doesn't show its child. Any way to retain children node when searching Parent node.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have something to do with the way you're binding the items, because I am able to filter on child nodes just fine in my example using your JS.

Check that this._oList.getItems() has all the items in it before you do the filter.

I'll post my code, so you can rebuild my project and get a feel for how it works.  Let me know if you have more questions.

Page.view.xml

```
  <mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.m.sample.Tree.Page"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <SearchField value="{json>/search}" search="onSearch"/>
        <Tree
            id="Tree"
            items="{path: '/'}">
            <StandardTreeItem title="{text}"/>
        </Tree>
</mvc:View>
```

Page.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller', 'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel', 'sap/ui/model/Filter', 'sap/ui/model/FilterOperator'],
function(Controller, JSONModel, Filter, FilterOperator) {
    "use strict";

    var PageController = Controller.extend("sap.m.sample.Tree.Page", {
        onInit: function(evt) {
            // set explored app's demo model on this sample
            var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.m.sample.Tree", "/Tree.json"));
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);

            var oJSONModel = new JSONModel();
            this.getView().setModel("json", oJSONModel);

            this._oList = this.byId("Tree");
            this._oListFilterState = {
                aFilter: [],
                aSearch: []
            };
        },

        onSearch: function(oEvent) {
            if (oEvent.getParameters().refreshButtonPressed) {
                this.onRefresh();
                return;
            }

            var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
            if (sQuery) {
                this._oListFilterState.aSearch = [new Filter("text", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)];
            } else {
                this._oListFilterState.aSearch = [];
            }
            this._applyFilterSearch();
        },

        _applyFilterSearch: function() {
            var aFilters = this._oListFilterState.aSearch.concat(this._oListFilterState.aFilter);
                //oViewModel = this.getModel();

            this._oList.getBinding("items").filter(aFilters, "Application");

            // if (aFilters.length !== 0) {
            //  oViewModel.setProperty("/noDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataWithFilterOrSearchText"));
            // } else if (this._oListFilterState.aSearch.length > 0) {
            //  oViewModel.setProperty("/noDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataText"));
            // }
        }

    });

    return PageController;

});
```

Tree.json

```
[
{
    "text": "Node1",
    "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-audio",
    "nodes":
    [
        {
            "text": "Node1-1",
            "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-e-pub",
            "nodes":[
                {
                    "text": "Node1-1-1",
                    "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-html"
                },
                {
                    "text": "Node1-1-2",
                    "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-photo",
                    "nodes":[
                        {
                            "text": "Node1-1-2-1",
                            "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-text-file",
                            "nodes":[
                                {
                                    "text": "Node1-1-2-1-1",
                                    "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-video"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "Node1-1-2-1-2",
                                    "ref": "sap-icon://attachment-zip-file"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": "Node1-1-2-1-3",
                                    "ref": "sap-icon://course-program"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "Node1-2",
            "ref": "sap-icon://create"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "Node2",
    "ref": "sap-icon://customer-financial-fact-sheet"
}
```

]

That's all you should need, but just incase you need these as well...
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Tree - Basic</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-preload="async"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.m.sample.Tree": "./", "sap.ui.demo.mock": "mockdata"}'>
    </script>

    <!-- Application launch configuration -->
    <script>

        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            new sap.m.App ({
                pages: [
                    new sap.m.Page({
                        title: "Tree - Basic",
                        enableScrolling : true,
                        content: [ new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                            name : "sap.m.sample.Tree"
                        })]
                    })
                ]
            }).placeAt("content");
        });

    </script>
</head>

<!-- UI Content -->
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content" role="application">
</body>
```

Component.js

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/UIComponent'],
function(UIComponent) {
"use strict";

var Component = UIComponent.extend("sap.m.sample.Tree.Component", {

    metadata : {
        rootView : "sap.m.sample.Tree.Page",
        dependencies : {
            libs : [
                "sap.m",
                "sap.ui.layout"
            ]
        },
        config : {
            sample : {
                files : [
                    "Page.view.xml",
                    "Page.controller.js",
                    "Tree.json"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});

return Component;
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have implemented your example with code for my OData service and the situation's still the same. However, thanks for pointing out the getItems() function. Before calling the filter() function, there are only the four root items in the responsoe of the getItems() function. Nevertheless, if I collapse a node, the getItems() function also returns, in addition to the root nodes, all the collapsed nodes. But even if they are in the getItems() response, I'm not able to filter them.

Comment: What happens if you remove? parameters : {
                expand: 'ChildGroupNodes',
                navigation: {
                    'GroupNodes': 'ChildGroupNodes'
                    }

I'm guessing you don't get the children nodes?

Comment: Precisely, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to solve your problem, but I actually did this exact thing a few months ago.

In your controller, put the following function:

```
    onSearch: function(oEvent) {

        var searchVal = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");
        var treeFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Text", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchVal);
        var oBinding = this.getView().byId("tree").mBindingInfos.rows.binding;

        oBinding.filter(treeFilter, FilterType.Application);
        oBinding.expandToLevel(3);
    },
```

And this should work straight away. Whatever you enter in the search box, it will populate the tree (up to 3 levels, but this can be changed) with your filter.

The onSearch function is of course executed on the livechange of the search field.