# Can you expand a sap.m.Tree via a navigation property?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've set up a `sap.m.Tree` bound to a "Blocks" entity set of a v2 OData service.

This pulls in all of the entities fine.

However, the "Blocks" entity has a navigation property named "ChildBlocks", which I want to show when expanding the tree.

How can this be done with sap.m.Tree?

I've tried the below code, to no avail.

```xml
<Tree xmlns="sap.m"
  id="nodes"
  items="{
    path: '/Blocks',
    templateShareable: false,
    properties: {
      navigation: {
        ChildBlock: '/ChildBlocks'
      }
  }"
><!-- ... --></Tree>
```

I get the below error:

> Neither navigation paths parameters, nor (complete/valid) tree hierarchy annotations where provided to the TreeBinding.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding tree via navigation property is *technically* possible but it's **deprecated**. According to the [API reference `v2.ODataModel#bindTree`](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/bindTree) parameter `navigation`:

> **Deprecated: since 1.44** The use of navigation properties to build up the hierarchy structure is deprecated. It is recommended to use the hierarchy annotations [...] instead.

Samples based on hierarchy annotations:

- Demo Kit: [`sap.m.Tree` with OData v2](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.Tree/sample/sap.m.sample.TreeOData)
- SO: [Client-side filtering `ODataTreeBinding`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296870/5846045)